# How to Refresh Table after ajax request in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am working on exchange project using laravel and want to refresh my table after a

```
<tbody class="fixed-header">
                                                             @foreach($transactionsCustomer as $transaction)
                                                             <tr>
                                                                 <td>{{ $transaction->description }}</td>
                                                                 @foreach($accounts  as $account)
                                                                    @if($transaction->code == 0)
                                                                       @if($account->currency->id==$transaction->currency_id)
                                                                        <td>{{ $transaction->amount }}</td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        @else
                                                                            <td></td>
                                                                            <td></td>
                                                                        @endif
                                                                        @else
                                                                        @if($account->currency->id==$transaction->currency_id)
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>{{ $transaction->amount }}</td>
                                                                        @else
                                                                            <td></td>
                                                                            <td></td>
                                                                        @endif

                                                                    @endif

                                                                 @endforeach
                                                                 <td><a href="{{ route('transaction.edit',$transaction->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary" >سمون</a></td>  
                                                             </tr>
                                                             @endforeach   
                                                       </tbody>
```

and here is my ajax code to store the data

```
   $("#transaction-form").submit(function(stay){
   var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // here $(this) refere to the form its submitting
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('transaction.store') }}",
        data: formdata, // here $(this) refers to the ajax object not form
        success: function (data) {
          $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
            updateTable();
        },
    });
    stay.preventDefault(); 
});
```

and here is my controller method to represent the data

```
public function singleCustomer(Request $request)
    {
        $customer = Customer::find($request->id);
        $accounts = Account::where('customer_id', $request->id)->get();
        $currencies = Currency::all();
       $transactionsCustomer = DB::table('transactions')->
        join('accounts','transactions.account_id' ,'=','accounts.id')->join('customers','accounts.customer_id','=','customers.id')->join('currencies','accounts.currency_id','=','currencies.id')->select('transactions.*','currencies.id as currency_id')->where('customers.id',$request->id)->get();
        return view('transaction.index',compact('currencies','customer','accounts','transactionsCustomer'));
    }
```

now i want to refresh my table after this ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the table in different view.

Here's the flow, you get all data from your **Controller** , pass it to the table view, in the main view you include the table view using **@include('table-view-route')**.

And don't forget on your success ajax, call **updateTable()** which has functionality to load the table view using jquery

```
$("#tableContainerId").load("{{url('table-view-route')}}");
```

Comment: i did the same as you said but don't work i don't know why

Comment: Have you attach the crsf_token to the ajax header? if you haven't do it, just add this
`$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});` and in your head layout view, add this `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`